# Why Bond pricing formula is changed?

Tags: fixed-income, interest

When I first learn about finance, a bond with continuous yield was priced via

$$Z = e^{-rT},$$ where $r$ is the yield, $T$ the time to maturity.

But, when I learned about stochastic interest rate models like [Ho-Lee](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/19351/bond-price-in-ho-lee-model) and Hull & White, etc. the formula changed to

$$Z= e^{A-Br},$$ where $A$, $B$ are functions.

What is the reason for it? Is there any reference which deal with this? I need explanation that is intuitive.

Comment: In the first formula, which is always true, $r$ is the interest rate (or YTM) for the term of the bond (i.e. the 7 year interest rate in the case of a 7 year bond). In the second formula $r_t$ is the *instantaneous i.r.*, or Spot Rate, which is the (annualized) rate for lending money for a short period if time, such as 1 day. You can use two different letters (such as $y$ and $r_t$) if you want.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the time $t$ price of a zero-coupon bond maturing at time $T$ is given by
\begin{align*}
P(t,T) &= \mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}\left[\exp\left(-\int_t^T r_s\mathrm{d}s\right) \Bigg|\mathcal{F}_t\right].
\end{align*}
Here, $r_t$ is the short rate, i.e. the cost for borrowing time from $t$ until $t+\mathrm{d}t$. This formula follows directly from the absence of arbitrage.

If $r_t\equiv r$ is constant, then
\begin{align*}
P(t,T)=e^{-r(T-t)},
\end{align*}
which is the first formula you mentioned.

If $r_t$ is time-varying, you have to used the above equation with the conditional expectations. As it happens, in the Ho-Lee and the Hull-White models (and others too), this conditional expectation can be written as
\begin{align*}
P(t,T)=e^{A(t,T)+r_tB(t,T)},
\end{align*}
for suitable functions $A,B$, see [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/50331/41821).

So both equations you mentioned are special cases of a more general formula. The first special case assumes constant interest rates, the second one assumes normally distributed short rates.